Create distance buffer for virtual layer with categorized symbology QGIS 3.34
I want to create a virtual layer with a fixed buffer distance e.g. 1000 m from a buliding layer as input. The building layer contains information about its use in colum X of its attribute table. The resulting buffer shall have a categorized symbology based on the use of the building, e.g. hospital is red, residential houses are green and so on....
Is ist also possible to create a model for that purpose? I was already able to create the buffer, but not classified according to the building use.

Questions should always state the exact software in use, and include a tag for that software.

For classified style, simply use Rendering Mode Categorized in Layer Styling and select the attribute. Be sure to include this attribute in the query for the virtual layer.

I know how to change the style via the rendering mode in the Layer Styling panel, but how do I include the categorized attribute in the query for the virtual layer?
